# jQuery After() method doesn't work with id attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-after

The below code is working fine. But if i change the html string in newPara() to `<textarea></textarea><button id="someId">Save</button>` or `<textarea></textarea><input type="button" value="Save"/>` its not working. What is the problem in this?

I need that id attribute to remove the newly attached html.

Any Suggestions!

Thanks!

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      p { background:yellow; font-weight:bold; cursor:pointer; padding:5px; }
      p.over { background: #ccc; }
      span { color:red; }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="aDiv">
      <p>Click me!</p>
    </div>

    <span></span>
    <script>
      $("body").delegate("p", "click", newPara);
      $("body").undelegate("button", "click", newPara).find("#adiv").html("<p>Click me!</p>");
      function newPara() {
        var html = "<textarea></textarea><button>Save</button>";
        $(this).after(html);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: with respect to the title, is it really the `after` _event_? [api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/after/) describes it as a method... and it's not listed on the [api.jquery.com events page](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) either...

Comment: ... and what was the original String which was working? And how is it not working now? Does all the JavaScript stop? Does it just not do what you expect?

Comment: @LeguRi: Sorry, i am newbie in jquery. Thanks for sharing!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My only guess would be that you're using double quotes to create the string literal, but also using them inside the string, therefore terminating it early.

If so, this:

```
"<textarea></textarea><button id="someId">Save</button>"
```

should be:

```
'<textarea></textarea><button id="someId">Save</button>'
```

Notice that I used single quotes on the outside, so that the inside ones don't close the string.

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/QQrHr/

The example uses your exact code. The only change I made was to use singe quotes around the string.

You could also escape the inner quotes if you wanted:

```
"<textarea></textarea><button id=\"someId\">Save</button>"
```

Comment: Thanks, shame on me. This is how i make mistakes :(

Comment: @NoobDevelopeR - You're welcome. That's an easy mistake to make. :o)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for append instead of after? Or even http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/ ?